# How to enter a parameter in Winform to be used in ReportViewer

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access, reportviewer

I am trying to learn how to use reportviewer in VS 2013. I know how to add a report and load it up with data but I am trying to add a parameter. The MS Access database contains one table called BasicForm and has 4 fields ID, firstName, lastName, and note.

```
                this.BasicFormTableAdapter.Fill(this.FormFillDBDataSet.BasicForm);

                this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

this is the code to load the report. Now according to [YouTube Instruction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQvWNAldA1E) I have to enter this SQL syntax.

`SELECT BasicForm.ID, BasicForm.firstName, BasicForm.lastName, BasicForm.note
FROM BasicForm
WHERE BasicForm.firstName=@x`

Then I have to enter to go back to code where I load up the report and enter the string that would be the value of parameter, as written below:

```
                this.BasicFormTableAdapter.Fill(this.FormFillDBDataSet.BasicForm, "Gaston");

                this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

but it does not work because VS will give me a SQL syntax error so I changed it as such:

`SELECT BasicForm.ID, BasicForm.firstName, BasicForm.lastName, BasicForm.note
FROM BasicForm
WHERE BasicForm.firstName=[x]`

Just as I would write it in MS access and it would work but then when I went back to the code to add the string that would be the value of the parameter, VS would give me an error message of unknown method. I am sure I am writing the syntax wrong but I am new to c# so no idead how to rewrite it the correct way.
 
Thank you for helping

Comment: Have you tried to execute the SQL code on C#, retrieve a DataSet and binding the DataSet to the Report?

Comment: yes I did but it keeps asking me that need a value for the parameter... How to enter the value of the parameter? I have no idea :(

Comment: Is this what you're having troubles with? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx